Misplaced \crcr. and other errors on latex
I tried all that i can with this. in \maketitle is showing some errors.

Misplaced \crcr.
Missing } inserted.
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
Missing \cr inserted.
Misplaced \crcr.


\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\begin{document}

\title{my title\\

\thanks{}
}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{1\textsuperscript{st} me}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{then \\
\textit{my university}\\
city \\
email}
}
}

\maketitle

thanks in advance.

You shouldn't put formatting instructions in macros like \author. The class will format the text in the way the journal wants the text to look like.
